# Bootstrap select in input group

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, html-select, bootstrap-4

So I just bought this theme "My City", and it's bootstrap based. The problem is that it has a search box, with a dropdown button next to it. I want it to be a select instead of a button. Currently if I simply change from  to  it will not be in the input group anymore and it will not be bounded to the search box. [Here you can see a preview of the theme](http://matveyan.ru/Themes/mycity/02.Default_Light/html/index.html).
You can see a dropdown with "Market" typed on it. It currently is a dropdown, but I want it to be a select.

Here is the input group's code:

```
<div class="input-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="...">
<div class="input-group-btn btn_cat">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" datatoggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
<span><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Market<span class="caret"></span></span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right place_dd" role="menu">
<li><a class="cinema"><i class="fa fa-film"></i>Cinema</a></li>
<li><a class="club"><i class="fa fa-beer"></i>Club</a></li>
<li><a class="cafe"><i class="fa fa-cutlery"></i>Cafe</a></li>
<li><a class="sport"><i class="fa fa-futbol-o"></i>Sport</a></li>
<li><a class="port"><i class="fa fa-life-ring"></i>Port</a></li>
<li><a class="bank"><i class="fa fa-university"></i>Bank</a></li>
<li><a class="post"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>Post</a></li>
<li><a class="showplace"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i>Showplace</a></li>
<li><a class="park"><i class="fa fa-leaf"></i>Park</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="input-group-btn btn_promo_search">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Search</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The mark-up in your html is incorrect.
Basic markup for select looks like this.

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Apologies, the code I have pasted was just experimental. I do realize that was incorrect. I have edited it now.